# Finding the distance from a point to a $R^m$ restricted area in $R^n$

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computational-geometry

The problem is described below:

[image]

When m=2 and n=3, it is basically finding the distance between a point and a line segment in $R^3$.

But when both m and n are larger, do I have to use a generic optimizer to solve this, or this problem can be precisely solved with mathematics, like the case when m=2 and n=3?

What I have done for now:

Approach A:

I tried to solve it with Gram–Schmidt process and projection but got stuck.

For example, the following R code:

```
P <- c(1,1,1,1)

m <- rbind(c(1,-1,1,2)*1/3,c(1,2,1,1)*1/5)

m2 <- qr.Q(qr(t(m)))

P2 <- P%*%m2[,1]*m2[,1]+P%*%m2[,2]*m2[,2]
```

It does not take into account the restriction $w_1+w_2=1$

Approach B:

Tried to solve it with lagrangian optimization, but also got stuck there.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a matrix $M$ and vector $y$, you are trying to find a vector $x$ that minimizes $\|Mx-y\|_2$, subject to $x \ge 0$ and $\|x\|_1=1$.

Without the additional constraints on $x$, this would be a [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) problem, which could be solved through linear algebra (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares), or with gradient descent.

With those additional constraints, you might try [projected gradient descent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571068/what-is-the-difference-between-projected-gradient-descent-and-ordinary-gradient).

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Here is a way to solve my problem. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21565/how-do-i-fit-a-constrained-regression-in-r-so-that-coefficients-total-1